# ImportError: No module named cv2 when executing Python script

Tags: python

I need to execute a Python application, but I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "dataset.py", line 8, in  import cv2 ImportError: No module named cv2

I have followed the face detection concept in [96 boards](http://www.96boards.org/blog/part-1-home-surveillance-project-96boards), but I keep getting above error message, when I run the script like this:

```
sudo python dataset.py
```

Comment: Install cv2 module, using pip. `pip install cv2`

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed openCV?

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

If you want install it with pip:

```
pip install opencv
```

Comment: Maybe use `pip` for python?

Comment: installing the deb package certainly seems like the easier solution